# How to explicitly declare routes for assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-routing, rails-assets

I have an app where the routes are:

```
# many routes go here

# last item in routes.rb:
get ':username' => 'users#show'
```

This allows routes of the form [www.example.com/your_username](http://www.example.com/your_username)

This works perfectly, however, it seems to cause a bug with asset/image urls.

Is there a way to explicitly define (the default) asset/image routes? (I figure if they're placed **before** the last line, then they should function as normal)

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#changing-the-assets-path

Comment: @Eyeslandic it doesn't say where paths like `/assets/..` and `/images/..` are defined?